# Split on first/nth occurrence of delimiter

Tags: regex, r

I am trying something I thought would be easy.  I'm looking for a single regex solution (though others are welcomed for completeness).  I want to split on n occurrences of a delimiter.

Here is some data:

```
x <- "I like_to see_how_too"
pat <- "_"
```

**Desired outcome**

*Say I want to split on first occurrence of `_`:*

```
[1] "I like"  "to see_how_too"
```

*Say I want to split on second occurrence of `_`:*

```
[1] "I like_to see"   "how_too"
```

Ideally, if the solution is a regex one liner generalizable to nth occurrence; the solution will use `strsplit` with a single regex.

Here's a solution that doesn't fit my parameters of single regex that works with `strsplit`

```
x <- "I like_to see_how_too"
y <- "_"
n <- 1
loc <- gregexpr("_", x)[[1]][n]

c(substr(x, 1, loc-1), substr(x, loc + 1, nchar(x)))
```

Comment: Could you write a function that pastes together a regex pattern based on a user-defined `n`? For example, if `n <- 3` then you can paste a (arbitrary) regex together as  `paste0("[a-z]{", n, "}")`

Comment: @hwnd - I was thinking that might work well for your answer

Comment: Oh, well then...carry on!  Haha

Comment: @RichardScriven updated, good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another solution using the `gsubfn` package and some regex-fu. To change the `nth` occurrence of the delimiter, you can simply swap the number that is placed inside of the range quantifier — `{n}`.

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- 'I like_to see_how_too'
strapply(x, '((?:[^_]*_){1})(.*)', c, simplify =~ sub('_$', '', x))
# [1] "I like"  "to see_how_too"
```

If you would like the nth occurrence to be *user defined*, you could use the following:

```
n <- 2
re <- paste0('((?:[^_]*_){',n,'})(.*)')
strapply(x, re, c, simplify =~ sub('_$', '', x))
# [1] "I like_to see" "how_too"
```

Comment: Please... never use such construct `(?:[^_]*(?:_)?){3}` to match `token separator token separator token` form. It's the most common cause for catastrophic backtracking http://regex101.com/r/rH6sM0/1 . Use `(?:[^_]*_){3}(.*)` instead.

Comment: The problem with implementing the regex you provide would be that the `_` delimiter would be included in the first group, but I edited and fixed that along with an adjusted regex.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than split you do match to get your split strings.

Try this regex:

```
^((?:[^_]*_){1}[^_]*)_(.*)$
```

Replace `1` by `n-1` where you're trying to get split on `nth` occurrence of underscore.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uS7xP2/1)

**Update:** It seems `R` also supports PCRE and in that case you can do `split` as well using this PCRE regex:

```
^((?:[^_]*_){1}[^_]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|_
```

**Replace `1` by `n-1` where you're trying to get split on `nth` occurrence of underscore.**

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.

#### [RegEx Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/uS7xP2/2)

```
x <- "I like_to see_how_too"

strsplit(x,  "^((?:[^_]*_){0}[^_]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|_", perl=TRUE)
strsplit(x,  "^((?:[^_]*_){1}[^_]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|_", perl=TRUE)

## > strsplit(x,  "^((?:[^_]*_){0}[^_]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|_", perl=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "I like" "to see" "how"    "too"   

## > strsplit(x,  "^((?:[^_]*_){1}[^_]*)(*SKIP)(*F)|_", perl=TRUE)
## [[1]]
## [1] "I like_to see" "how_too"
```

Comment: The second solution works well, couldn't get it to split on the first occurrence. +1

Comment: [You can use this to split on 1st occurrence of `_`](http://regex101.com/r/uS7xP2/3)

Comment: In R (probably not all compilers) this will split on all occurrences of `_`.

Comment: But isn't `R` using PCRE engine? regex101 PCRE is only splitting it on 1st occurrence

Comment: I thought so but I added the output showing how it turns out in R.

Comment: I don't know `R` good enough but try: **`strsplit(gsub("^((?:[^_]*_){0}+[^_]*)_", "\\1~", x, perl=TRUE), "~")` [as in this demo](http://ideone.com/aCzPVO)**. This gives `"I like"` and `"to see_how_too"` after split.

Answer (score 3):

### Non-Solution

Since R is using PCRE, you can use `\K` to remove everything that matches the pattern before `\K` from the main match result.

Below is the regex to split the string at the 3rd `_`

```
^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){2}\K_
```

If you want to split at the nth occurrence of `_`, just change `2` to (n - 1).

[**Demo on regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/vQ1vM3/1)

**That was the plan. However, `strsplit` seems to think differently.**

### Actual execution

[**Demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/lfpKCL)

```
x <- "I like_to see_how_too but_it_seems to_be_impossible"
strsplit(x, "^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*)\\K_", perl=TRUE)
strsplit(x,  "^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){1}\\K_", perl=TRUE)
strsplit(x,  "^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){0}\\K_", perl=TRUE)

# strsplit(x, "^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*)\\K_", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "I like_to see" "how_too but"   "it_seems to"   "be_impossible"

# strsplit(x,  "^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){1}\\K_", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "I like_to see" "how_too but"   "it_seems to"   "be_impossible"

# strsplit(x,  "^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){0}\\K_", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "I like"     "to see"     "how"        "too but"    "it"        
# [6] "seems to"   "be"         "impossible"
```

It still fails to work on a stronger assertion `\A`

```
strsplit(x,  "\\A[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){0}\\K_", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "I like"     "to see"     "how"        "too but"    "it"        
# [6] "seems to"   "be"         "impossible"
```

### Explanation?

This behavior hints at the fact that `strsplit` find the first match, do a substring to extract the first token and the remainder part, and find the next match in the remainder part.

This removes all the states from the previous matches, and **leaves us with a clean state** when it tries to match the regex on the remainder. This makes the task of stopping the `strsplit` function at first match and achieving the task at the same time impossible. There is not even a parameter in `strsplit` to limit the number of splits.

Comment: I couldn't get it to split on the first occurrence though by using `{0}`

Comment: @TylerRinker: R seems to substring the rest of the string after the first match, and attempt to match the regex again, instead of continuing the match. This causes the `^` to be recognized as start of the string right in the middle of the string.

Comment: @TylerRinker: A demo of the problem: http://ideone.com/lfpKCL Actually, this solution doesn't work at all in R, due to the way it handle the splitting.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I have concluded that a solution for `strsplit` is impossible. There is **absolutely** nothing for you to work with that can differentiate the initial input and the remainder of the input after splitting.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, If the length is greater than 1, it is re-cycled (repeated). `strsplit` is not the right tool here.

Comment: I think the answer here then is `strsplit` can't get the job done with a single regex.  Folks much smarter than I have exhausted this.  It seems @anubhava gives a valuable alternative using `gsub` and `strsplit`.  Probably the best hoped for solution.  The `stringi` package's `stri_split_regex` function does allow for `n` splits.  So perhaps your thinking can be used there or more generally, `stringi::stri_split_regex(x, "_", 2)`.

Comment: @TylerRinker This can be done using a different method similar to strsplit, I'll provide an answer when I get home this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

This uses `gsubfn` to to preprocess the input string so that `strsplit` can handle it.  The main advantage is that one can specify a vector of numbers, `k`, indicating which underscores to split on.

It replaces the occurrences of underscore defined by `k` by a double underscore and then splits on double underscore.  In this example we split at the 2nd and 4th underscore:

```
library(gsubfn)

k <- c(2, 4) # split at 2nd and 4th _

p <- proto(fun = function(., x) if (count %in% k) "__" else "_")
strsplit(gsubfn("_", p, "aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff"), "__")
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] "aa_bb" "cc_dd" "ee_ff"
```

If empty fields are allowed then use any other character sequence not in the string, e.g. `"\01"` in place of the double underscore.

See section 4 of the gusbfn vignette for more info on using `gusbfn` with proto objects to retain state between matches.