# Split a string into two parts after the first word?

Tags: r, string

For example, I have a string

```
x <- 'what are you talking about'
```

How do I split it into two strings `'what'` and `'are you talking about'`?

Comment: something abnormal like `strsplit(sub(' ', '$', x), '[$]')[[1]]`

Comment: Relevant to this discussion: [split on first/nth occurrence of delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301424/split-on-first-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

Do matching instead of splitting.

```
> x <- 'what are you talking about'
> library(stringi)
> stri_extract_all(x, regex="^\\S+|\\S.*")[[1]]
[1] "what"                          
[2] "are you talking about"
```

**OR**

```
> library(stringr)
> str_split(x, perl("^\\S+\\K\\s+"))
[[1]]
[1] "what"                          
[2] "are you talking about"
```

Comment: Nice.  What would change in the code to split the string after the second word?

Comment: @lawyeR so simple `str_split(x, perl("^\\S+\\s+\\S+\\K\\s+"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it long hand, since `strsplit` won't play nice here:

```
val <- regexpr("\\s",x)
substring(x, c(1,val+1), c(val-1,nchar(x)) )
#[1] "what"                           "are you talking about"
```