# Substitute/remove after nth occurrence of substring in string

Tags: regex, r

I'd like a regex for sub in R to substitute the characters in a string which follow the nth occurrence of ";" in that string, where n is a variable number passed to the regex.

```
  stringA="a; b; c; d; e; f; g; h; i; j;"

    stringB<-sub("^(;){4}.*", "", stringA)
##---------------^My attempt at a regular expression here-------
```

Desired output:

```
stringB
    "a; b; c; d;"
```

Comment: Try [`stringB <- sub("^((?:[^;]*;){4}).*", "\\1", stringA)`](http://ideone.com/257xfn).

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301424/split-on-first-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter

Comment: You could always just use strsplit and avoid the complexity of regex altogether: `paste(strsplit(stringA, ";")[[1]][1:4],collapse=";")` or even `substr(stringA, 1, gregexpr(";", stringA)[[1]][4])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^((?:[^;]*;){4}).*
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:[^;]*;){4})` - (Group 1) captures a substring comprising 4 (or any number you pass with `s` variable) occurrences of

  - `[^;]*` - 0 or more symbols other than `;`
  - `;` - a literal semi-colon
- `.*` - 0 or more characters, as many as possible

Using backreference `\\1` in the replacement pattern we restore the leading substring in the result.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/w79TVG) (here, the limit threshold is passed as a string):

```
stringA="a; b; c; d; e; f; g; h; i; j;"
s <- "4"
stringB <- sub(sprintf("^((?:[^;]*;){%s}).*", s), "\\1", stringA)
stringB
##  "a; b; c; d;"
```

Or, if you pass an integer value

```
s <- 4
sub(sprintf("^((?:[^;]*;){%d}).*", s), "\\1", stringA)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/TOg6eB)

Comment: Is there a way to make "n" in {n} a variable defined earlier?

Comment: It is a variable `s`, you can define it earlier.

Comment: Thanks, that works, I hadn't noticed the sprintf method!