# delete string before some "." r

Tags: r, regex, string, parsing

How can I delete a string after the 6th dot while including the first value right after the 6th dot?

example string:

```
data <- c("A.5.MD.c3.M.5.20.M.5.20b_targ.sco.ab" , "A.5.MD.c3.M.5.21_targ.sco.ab")
```

desired output: (keep 6 dots)

```
desired.data <- c("A.5.MD.c3.M.5.20" , "A.5.MD.c3.M.5.21")
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Substitute/remove after nth occurrence of substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425444/substitute-remove-after-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-string). In your case--looks like `sub("^((?:[^.]*\\.){6}\\d+).*", "\\1", data)`

Comment: Also, the `_targ` is before the 7th dot. Do you want that included?

Comment: let me update in a better way.

Comment: Did you try the `sub()` regex I posted as well? I added digits `\\d+` to the capture group (captured with parentheses, returned using `"\\1"`). It works for me but let me know if it does not work for you.

Comment: @Andrew this solved the puzzle. Thanks for your time! :) If you post here, I will accept it as the correct.

Comment: Would there ever be an _ anywhere else in the strings? And what would you want if there was an _ within the first 6 .-delimited groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub("^((?:[^.]*\\.){6}\\d*).*", "\\1", data)`. The pattern is better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425528/10112285).

This basically captures the combination of optional `*` non-period character(s) `[^.]*` and period `\\.` six `{6}` times, and also captures any possible trailing digits `\\d*` after the 6th period. More concisely, it grabs everything before the 6th period (inclusive), and the digits immediately after.

```
sub("^((?:[^.]*\\.){6}\\d*).*", "\\1", data)
[1] "A.5.MD.c3.M.5.20" "A.5.MD.c3.M.5.21"
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression way:

```
desired.data = sub('(([^.]+\\.){6}[^.]+).*','\\1',data)
```

Can't remember regular expressions way:

```
desired.data = unlist(
  lapply(
    strsplit(data,'.',fixed=T),
    function(x) paste0(x[1:7],collapse='.')
  )
)
```

In your question, your desired output also has "_targ" removed from the seventh .-delimited group, but you don't mention by what implicit rule you imagine that should occur, so I'll assume you just don't like the string "_targ" and remove it here as well in this post-processing step:

```
desired.data = sub('_targ','',desired.data,fixed=T)
```

Or remove all _*:

```
desired.data = gsub('_[^.]+','',desired.data)
```