# Regex - Replace part of url

Tags: javascript, regex, redirect

I want to replace a part of url:

```
Origin-> https://example.u-test.com/ex-2<br>


Destination-> https://example.u-test.com/ex <br>
```

So what I want is to remove part after "-" but only in the second part after first slash.

With `url.replace(/ *\-[^.]*\. */g, ".")` I get:

https://example.u.com/ex-2

**I want to remove "-2" after ex, not "-test" in the first part.**

What is the right regex expression?

Comment: show the code so we can help out

Comment: Why a regular expression? Why not `.split()`?

Comment: Do you want answers only in regx?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425528/7918125 try this

Comment: I would say build an [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object from the url and then operate on the `pathname` property instead of the whole url

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URL` interface for that. it allows you to easily read and modify the different components of a given URL.

```js
const url =  new URL("https://example.u-test.com/ex-2");

const domain = url.hostname;
const pathname = url.pathname;
const part = pathname.split("-")[0];

console.log(domain + part);
```

Comment: You don't need to take the different parts of the URL object out, you can simply set the `.pathname` property to the new value and `toString()` the instance, or `.href` property to get back the new url string

Answer (score 0):

In case you absolutely want to do this with regular expressions:

```js
const url = "https://example.u-test.com/ex-2"
const result = url.replace(/-[^-]*$/g, "")
console.log(result)
```

**Explanation:**
If you want to remove the part after the last slash or dash, you should begin your match on that point. The above regular expression starts matching at the last dash (`-`) character in the line. Regex will match only the last dash because the subsequent characters it searches for is everything except another dash, followed by the end of the line (`$`).

- `-` matches a dash (`-`) character
- `[^-]*` matches everything except for another dash
- `$` after the dash and the non-dash characters, there must be the end of the line

Comment: `[A-z]` includes `A-Za-z` and also `[\]&_` and the backtick, but does not include many other things such as `!"#$%&'()*+,` etc. or common accented characters. You should use either `[A-Za-z]` or `[A-Z]/gi` if you mean ascii alphanumerics, or use `[^-]` if you mean _"everything except another dash"_. `[A-z]` is an anti-pattern (no pun intended). You also don't need to escape the initial dash `\-` is the same as `-`.

Comment: Didn't know that [A-z] is an anti-pattern. Thanks for clarifying! I've updated the answer.