# How to count the number of underscores and split the string on the middle one only?

Tags: r, string

I would like to count the number of underscores and split the string into two different strings at the middle underscore.

```
strings <- c('aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff', 'cc_hh_ff_zz", "bb_dd")
```

Desired Output:

```
First        Last
"aa_bb_cc"   "dd_ee_ff"
"cc_hh"      "ff_zz"
"bb"         "dd"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split on first/nth occurrence of delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301424/split-on-first-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter)

Comment: What happens when there are an even number of underscores (e.g., `aa_bb_cc`)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cludgy solution that assumes that there are always an odd number of underscores.

```r
# Load libraries
library(stringr)

# Define function
even_split <- function(s){
  # Split string
  tmp <- str_split(s, "_")

  lapply(tmp, function(x){
    # Patch string back together in two pieces
    c(paste(x[1:(length(x)/2)], collapse = "_"),
      paste(x[(1+length(x)/2):length(x)], collapse = "_"))
  })
}

# Example
strings <- c('aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff', 'cc_hh_ff_zz', 'bb_dd')

# Test function
even_split(strings)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "aa_bb_cc" "dd_ee_ff"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "cc_hh" "ff_zz"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "bb" "dd"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Adapting nhahtdh's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301424/split-on-first-nth-occurrence-of-delimiter), all you need to do is add a step to count the underscores (done here with `str_count`) and return the median number of underscores.

```
library(stringr)

strsplit(
  strings, 
  paste0("^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){", str_count(strings, '_') %/% 2, "}\\K_"), 
  perl = TRUE)

# [[1]]
# [1] "aa_bb_cc" "dd_ee_ff"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "cc_hh" "ff_zz"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "bb" "dd"
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes an odd number of underscores, and 99 or fewer.

```
library(stringr)
library(strex)
strings <- c('aa_bb_cc_dd_ee_ff', 'cc_hh_ff_zz', 'bb_dd')

splitMiddleUnderscore <- function(x){
    nUnderscore <- str_count(x, '_')
    middleUnderscore <- match(nUnderscore, seq(1, 99, 2))
    str1 <- str_before_nth(x, '_',  middleUnderscore)
    str2 <- str_after_nth(x, '_', middleUnderscore)
    c(str1, str2)
}

lapply(strings, splitMiddleUnderscore)

#[[1]]
#[1] "aa_bb_cc" "dd_ee_ff"

#[[2]]
#[1] "cc_hh" "ff_zz"

#[[3]]
#[1] "bb" "dd"
```

Comment: you can use `middleUnderscore <- str_count(x, '_') %/% 2 + 1` to avoid the "99 or fewer" requirement.